# react native module not found createreactnativecomponentclass

Tags: react-native

I am getting this error. It seems like a module is not found but its there

[image]

Comment: This happens sometimes, especially if you installed a new module while the development server is running. Try the suggested steps at the bottom of the error (clear watchman watches, delete `node_modules` and install them again, and reset package manager cache), all while the development server is off. Then try starting it again.

Comment: how do you clear watchman watches?

Comment: You can use this command taken from [here](https://gist.github.com/jarretmoses/c2e4786fd342b3444f3bc6beff32098d) to do everything: `watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* && rm -rf node_modules/ && npm cache clean && npm install && npm start -- --reset-cache`